# Choose which secret key to use when doing a gpg --encrypt --sign

Tags: gnupg

I have multiple secret keys in my GPG keyring.

I'd like to do a `gpg -e -s -a` to encrypt, sign, and ascii armor the output.  However, I also need to specify *which* secret key to use for the signature, by key id.

Answer (score 42):

I needed the --local-user option.

```
gpg -e -s -a --local-user 0xDEADBEEF -r 0x01234567
```

Comment: Just for the record: `--local-user` or `-u` for short.

Comment: I didn't understand why you needed to use local user

Comment: If you have multiple keys and want to sign the fourth key with the third key, (when gpg defaults to the first key) then you need -u --local-user to specify the key that is doing the signing.

Comment: For those who probably do not know,‍`-e, --encrypt` , `-s, --sign` , `-a, --armor` , `-r, --recipient` , `-u , --local-user`