# How to select the GnuPG key that the maven-gpg-plugin uses to sign artifacts?

Tags: java, maven, gnupg

I am using the maven-gpg-plugin to sign the maven artifacts. This works fine, but I have several keys in my GnuPG keyring and want to use a different one than the one GnuPG selects.

1. How does GnuPG select the "default" key if there are several ones?
2. Is there a possibility to specify the key to be used in the maven-gpg-plugin configuration? It seems that `keyname` doesn't work (I assume it selects the keyring, but not a specific key).

Comment: There are plenty of parameters to try. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html.

Comment: All those parameters specify (at least according to their description) the keyring, but not the key within the keyring.

Comment: You can try `gpgArguments` with http://stackoverflow.com/q/9624384/1700321.

Comment: 1.) It seems that GPG just selects the first one in the ring.

Comment: 2.)     <configuration>
     <keyname>0xA9D0740E</keyname>
    </configuration> works. There seems to be some confusion on the GPG side on the words user, key, id and name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does GPG select the "default" key if there are several ones?

GnuPG by default chooses the first key in the secret keyring, if not defined otherwise (for example, using the `default-key` option). From `man gpg`:

```
--default-key name

    Use name as the default key to sign with. If this option is not used,
    the default key is the first key found in the secret keyring. Note 
    that -u or --local-user overrides this option.
```

> Is there a possibility to specify the key to be used in the maven-gpg-plugin configuration? It seems that "keyname" doesn't work (I assume it selects the keyring, but not a specific key).

If you do not want to have GnuPG decide automatically which key to use, `<keyname>[keyname]</keyname>` selects to key to be used. I expect this is passed as the `local-key` option, so it should support short and long key IDs, fingerprints and user IDs. The GnuPG manual contains a [list of ways to specify keys](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Specify-a-User-ID.html).

Most manuals describing how to specify keys here use the short key ID, which I strongly recommend not to do so [because of collision attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74009/what-is-an-openpgp-key-id-collision/74010#74010), and using the whole fingerprint instead.

There are further options to change the selection of keys. Refer to the [Maven GnuPG plugin manual](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html) for more details on the individual options:

- Selecting a dedicated keyring using [`secretKeyring`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html#secretKeyring)
- Selecting a dedicated GnuPG home directory using [`homedir`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html#homedir)
- Passing the `local-user` option to GnuPG using [`gpgArguments`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html#gpgArguments)

Comment: According to the [`mvn-gpg-plugin` documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html#keyname), the `keyname` parameters is passed as `--local-user`.

Comment: None of the methods work anymore.