# Select the GnuPG key used in maven-gpg-plugin

Tags: java, maven, gnupg

I've seen [How to select the GnuPG key that the maven-gpg-plugin uses to sign artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372363/how-to-select-the-gnupg-key-that-the-maven-gpg-plugin-uses-to-sign-artifacts) and many more questions, but I still can't make this maven plugin work.

I've created 2 keys with gpg and now I can see them by doing:

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
-----------------------------
sec   rsa2048/835CAF6D1B0569EB 2017-12-12 [SC]
uid                 [ultimate] User 1 <email1@gmail.com>
ssb   rsa2048/7604C74FE62682EF 2017-12-12 [E]

sec   rsa2048/1330DF9E7C6D864E 2017-12-12 [SC]
uid                 [ultimate] User 2 <email2@gmail.com>
ssb   rsa2048/09982A57EC4B5F18 2017-12-12 [E]
```

my pom.xml is configured as follow:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>sign-artifacts</id>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>sign</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <keyname>1330DF9E7C6D864E</keyname>
        <passphrase>supersecurepassword</passphrase>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

but when I do "mvn package gpg:sign" it always uses key 835CAF6D1B0569EB
Standing to https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/sign-mojo.html, the keyname should send to gpg -u/--local-user, but it doesn't seem to work.
I've also tried to use "gpgArguments" and "--default-key", and I tried "0x1330DF9E7C6D864E" and "0x1330DF9E7C6D864E!" (that standing to documentation should force the key).
What's wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: > but when I do "mvn package gpg:sign" it always uses key 835CAF6D1B0569EB <

To be sure you're not checking some old files add _clean_ to maven call. Like this:

`mvn clean package gpg:sign`

Answer (score 2):

Add `gpg` prefix.

```
<gpg.keyname>1330DF9E7C6D864E</gpg.keyname>
<gpg.passphrase>supersecurepassword</gpg.passphrase>
```

Comment: `gpg` prefix is only necessary if config is passed via properties. If plugin is configured directly then `<keyname>` is correct (like the code in question).

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use only the last 8 characters (`7C6D864E`) of the signature key? And also trying to append to the beginning `0x` (`0x7C6D864E`)?

Also, try checking the signature keys

`gpg --list-signatures --keyid-format 0xshort`

`gpg --list-signatures --keyid-format 0xlong`

`gpg --list-signatures`

`gpg --list-signatures --keyid-format short`